# Best way to store a one-to-many column in database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, fieldtype

I have a `users` table in my database and have three kinds of user roles - manager(admin), expert, and student.

I have tried storing their role as column `role` in the `users` table, but my question is what is the best way to store it?

For example, should I use numbers - 1 for admin, 2 for expert and 3 for student. Or only one character - 'A' for admin , 'E' for expert and 'S' for student? Or full string 'admin' for admin and so on, or what?

**Edit**

Guys, I want most efficient way. Some of you told me to have another table but this relationship isn't many to many, it's one to many because users can only have one role.

Comment: This more depends on your use case and spec requirements, but if that was me, I would do something with normalization to make it more dynamic

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to have a separate junction table, eg `user_roles` that will have columns: `id`, `user_id` and `role_id`. This way each user can have multiple roles in the future, even if right now they only have 1.

And that `role_id` would point to a role in a new `roles` table, which could have all the data associated with the roles.

Or if you really don't want the junction table, then just put the `role_id` directly into your `users` table.

Look up database "normalization". Basically if you have a specific set of data that will be repeating in a column, you might want to put it in its own table.

Comment: any user only have one role

Comment: That might be true today but unless you can guarantee that it will stay true forever, follow the advice in this answer.

Comment: @Andrew this is not my answer , i want the way to store role column , so how to store role in the new table?

Comment: @DanBracuk this in not my answer , i want a way to store role column , i know how to normalize tables and relations

Answer (score 1):

You could create a separate table showing 2 columns: role_nbr, role with values like: 
1, Admin; 
2, Expert; 
3, Student

Then include role_nbr in your users table and use numbers, linking it to the role table to lookup the role name. That way, if you ever increase your roles, it's easy to add to the separate table. A good study would be on normalization - this will help you eliminate storing duplicate information where you have a lot of information to store (like the role name - since storing a number or letter - how would you remember what it stood for?)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `enum` type. Here is an example

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    -- the other columns
    role ENUM('admin, 'expert', 'student')
);
```

> An ENUM is a string object with a value chosen from a list of permitted values that are enumerated explicitly in the column specification at table creation time.

This means that the `enum` type has already defined values (and can contain **only one** value per row - you can't have a user who is `admin` and at the same time `student`). In your case, they are `admin`, `expert` and `student`.

[DOCS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html)